# Error animate group of patchs in arrays

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I got success to move paths in arrays on an element like this:

```
var c = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500);
var p = c.path("most code").attr({
    fill: '#33CCFF',
    stroke: '#000000',
    'stroke-width': 5
});
var times = [most code];
var paths = [most code];
var current=0;

    function nextStep(){
        if (current>paths.length)
           return;
        p.animate({
            path: paths[current]
        }, times[current++],nextStep);
    }
nextStep();
```

[jsfiddle and full code](http://jsfiddle.net/d7d3Z/222/)

But I would do the same through arrays of groups that contains the paths, I tried the same way however placing the groups in the arrays, I need to be in groups because each group will tell hundreds of paths to the element.

```
var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '500', '500');

// frame 1
var path3184 = rsr.path("most code").attr({
    "fill-rule": 'evenodd',
    "clip-rule": 'evenodd',
    fill: '#8FC876',
    id: 'path3184',
    parent: 'g3182',
    'stroke-width': '0',
    'stroke-opacity': '1'
}).data('id', 'path3184');

// frame 2
var path3186 = rsr.path("most code").attr({
    "fill-rule": 'evenodd',
    "clip-rule": 'evenodd',
    fill: '#2FA990',
    id: 'path3186',
    parent: 'g3182',
    'stroke-width': '0',
    'stroke-opacity': '1'
}).data('id', 'path3186');

// group 1
var g3182 = rsr.set();
g3182.push(
    path3184
);

// group 2
var g3183 = rsr.set();
g3183.push(
    path3186
);

// load next group function
var paths = [g3182, g3183];
var times = [1000, 1000];

var current=0

function nextStep(){
    if (current>paths.length)
       return;
    rsr.animate({
        path: paths[current]
    }, times[current++],nextStep);
}

nextStep();
```

[jsfiddle and full code](http://jsfiddle.net/dxyJN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change the line:

`rsr.animate({`
to
`g3182.animate({`

(Or whichever group you wish to animate.)

Comment: Could be also, the problem that there are many groups are correct then it would animate the variable arrays, can also be done with "requestAnimationFrame" but I have not the slightest idea how to insert it in the code, thanks.